# Get the type of a member in a Expression

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, lambda, expression-trees

I'm trying to learn expressions, and I cannot find how to get the member type of a property in a expression. For example, consider this method:

```
static IEnumerable<Y> Filter<X,Y>(this IEnumerable<Person> p,  Expression<Func<Person,X>> select,  Expression<Func<X, Y>> format)
{
    foreach (var item in p)
    {
        // member name
        var m = ((MemberExpression)select.Body).Member;

        // member attributes
        var attributes = m.GetCustomAttributes(false);

        // member type?

        var a = select.Compile().Invoke(item);
        var b = format.Compile().Invoke(a);
        m.ToString();
        yield return b;
    }
}
```

It doesn't do anything interesting, it is just for trying. If I do:

```
String y = _persons.Filter(p => p.DateOfBirth, d => d.ToString("yyyy")).ToArray().Single();
```

I can get in Y the year of the person in the collection. I want to know the type of "p.DateOfBirth" in the "Filter" method. How could I do that without using reflection?

Regards.

Comment: +1 for a nice effort to filter (project) and format in one functional programming-like flow. But can you clarify a bit? Is your question really how to replace `Person` in the `Filter` signature by a generic type parameter? Or did Jon hit the right key?

Comment: Thanks. It is just what Jon answered. The code is just part of several tests I'm using to try to understand expressions, and I wanted to know how to get the type of the member. Probably you are confused because I was asking something apparently so damn obvious :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I've understood you correctly, you just need the [`Expression.Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.type.aspx) property:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class Person
{
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Expression<Func<Person, DateTime>> expression = p => p.DateOfBirth;

        MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression) expression.Body;
        Console.WriteLine(memberExpression.Type); // Prints System.DateTime
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. It bothers me that it was so obvious and I didn't see it :D